# How frequently primary mongodb replicate data to secondary?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have three mongodb machine (1 primary and 2 secondary) with replication.
I know primary mongodb doing asynchronous write to secondary but how frequently ?

I read, it use oplog to write secondary but opslog minimum size will be in MB so what will happen if primary goes down before oplog size. ?

Is there any link for documentation where i can read mongodb internal process. ?

Comment: I found this closed issue based on your scenario, hope it could be useful https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-12058

Comment: This one about what happens (very detailed) behind the scenes https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/wiki/Replication-Internals

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to these two sources:

1. [MongoDB Replication Lag](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/troubleshoot-replica-sets/)
2. [MongoDB Ops Manager](https://docs.opsmanager.mongodb.com/current/reference/alerts/replication-lag/)